# Bundle Identifier Different from Provisioning Profile.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, provisioning-profile

I'm using a **wildcard provisioning profile**, which is the same as my bundle identifier except for the

`.* suffix` at the end.

When I try to archive my app, it says that the bundle identifier and provisioning profile aren't the same.

Well, duh. They can't be. The provisioning profile needs the `.*` and the bundle identifier explicitly can't have a `.* suffix` (the `*` is an illegal character)

How do I resolve this?

Comment: You can replace the * with any string in your bundle identifier

Comment: if you are using wildcard provisioning like com.yourdomain.* then your bundle identifier would be com.yourdomain.youappname (*)is replaced with name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some of Apple's info on wilcard App IDs.:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1713/_index.html

Basically you need to replace the asterisk in your bundle ID:

```
Provisioning profile: com.myapps.*
Bundle ID: com.myapps.thisapp
```